# Webstorm/PhpStorm: Select specific font from a Font Family

Tags: fonts, phpstorm, webstorm

WebStorm/PhpStorm: How do I choose a specific font from a font family? (for the editor).

Specifically, I have downloaded the `Source Code Pro` font. It comes with these typefaces: Extra Light, Light, Regular, Semibold, Bold. Now, I want to choose Extra Light/Light.

But, when trying to select a font, Webstorm only shows me one font for the entire family.

How do I make it use a specific one?

If it makes a difference, I am currently using Mac OS X Mountain Lion (but I'd be interested in finding the answer to this for Windows as well)

Answer (score 1):

Disable **Show only monospaced fonts** to see the full list:

[image]

Comment: I'd already tried that (and I checked again to confirm) but this doesn't seem to help. Isn't `Source Code Pro` a monospaced font in any case? 
Can you tell me how installed the fonts, and what OS are you using?

Comment: @HimanshuPokhariya: I was kind of surprised as well. I would have assumed it *is* a monospaced font, but it didn't show up unless I unchecked the box. I downloaded the font package from SourceForge and installed the fonts through the context menu option "Install". This is on Windows 7.

Comment: Downloaded and installed. Restarted. Doesn't work still. If anyone can this working on a Mac, do report back.

Comment: @HimanshuPokhariya: I'd recommend posting this in the [PhpStorm issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI).

Comment: Yeah I was going to. Will give it a day before I do that to see if there is a workaround of any sort.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into solving this exact issue myself, on a mac at least. You basically have to drop these font files into your java environment direcotry's font folder. PHPStorm being a java app utilizes fonts form these directories slightly different than the ones in your system fonts folder.

You should see the various options font weight options for source code pro once you have done this.

Blog post with more details & instructions, if you're interested:
http://sticksnglue.com/wordpress/?p=112

[image]